# using a function changing my average from Fahrenheit to Celsius

Tags: python

Hey guys.  I got my average number of 32.  I know that is freezing and it is 0 degrees in Celsius.  What I have to do is use a function write a program to display it in Celsius.  I know the Formula is C = (F - 32) * (5 / 9)

```
def fahrenToCel(32):
   return
```

(this is the part where I am stumped.. I don't know if i'm missing something obvious, or I approached it wrong)

Comment: What does this have to do with facebook?

Comment: What is 32 the average of?  Do you have a list of measurements?

Comment: @recursive: Looks like it's from the OP's previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641724/trouble-using-function-in-python. From the context of this question, it's apparently a Fahrenheit temperature.

Comment: "I don't know if i'm missing something obvious..." yes, you are. You are missing the point where you read some books or search the internet to get you started and then you post a question when you are truly stuck.

Comment: I think you need to go back to the basics and learn more about object oriented programming.

Comment: Obviously @user691693 is learning how to program. No need to throw it in their face. @user see [here](http://diveintopython.org/getting_to_know_python/declaring_functions.html) how to define Python functions. Or better, start from the beginning in that book!

Answer (score 4):

It's really simple:

```
def fahrenToCel(f):
    return (f - 32) * (5 / 9.0)
```

Comment: A function worth a thousand words.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, the 32 should be in your call, not your definition:

```
def fahrenToCel(f):
    # Code to convert to Celcius here
    return c

print fahrenToCel(32)
```